# How to make a GridSearchCV with a proper FunctionTransformer in a pipeline?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I'm trying to make a Pipeline with GridSearchCV to filter data (with iforest) and perform a regression with StandarSclaler+MLPRegressor.

I made a FunctionTransformer to include my iForest filter in the pipeline. I also define a parameters grid for the iForest filter (using kw_args methods).

All seems OK but when un mahe the fit, nothing happens ... No error message. Nothing.

After, when I want to make a predict, I have the message : "This RandomizedSearchCV instance is not fitted yet"

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

#Definition of the function auto_filter using the iForest algo
def auto_filter(DF, conta=0.1):
    #iForest made on the DF dataframe
    iforest = IsolationForest(behaviour='new', n_estimators=300, max_samples='auto', contamination=conta)
    iforest = iforest.fit(DF)

    # The DF (dataframe in input) is filtered taking into account only the inlier observations

data_filtered = DF[iforest.predict(DF) == 1]

    # Only few variables are kept for the next step (regression by MLPRegressor)
    # this function delivers X_filtered and y
    X_filtered = data_filtered[['SessionTotalTime','AverageHR','MaxHR','MinHR','EETotal','EECH','EEFat','TRIMP','BeatByBeatRMSSD','BeatByBeatSD','HFAverage','LFAverage','LFHFRatio','Weight']]
    y = data_filtered['MaxVO2']
    return (X_filtered, y)

#Pipeline definition ('auto_filter' --> 'scaler' --> 'MLPRegressor')    
pipeline_steps = [('auto_filter', FunctionTransformer(auto_filter)), ('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('MLPR', MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs', activation='relu', early_stopping=True, n_iter_no_change=20, validation_fraction=0.2, max_iter=10000))]

#Gridsearch Definition with differents values of 'conta' for the first stage of the pipeline ('auto_filter)
parameters = {'auto_filter__kw_args': [{'conta': 0.1}, {'conta': 0.2}, {'conta': 0.3}], 'MLPR__hidden_layer_sizes':[(sp_randint.rvs(1, nb_features, 1),), (sp_randint.rvs(1, nb_features, 1), sp_randint.rvs(1, nb_features, 1))], 'MLPR__alpha':sp_rand.rvs(0, 1, 1)}   

pipeline = Pipeline(pipeline_steps)

estimator = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=5, n_iter=10)
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Please, can you write the import statement for sp_rand?

Comment: Please, can you add a small dataset for testing?

Comment: Which format of dataset ? Csv ?

Comment: Csv is a good format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `func` parameter of `FunctionTransformer` should be a callable that accepts the
same arguments as `transform` method (array-like `X` of shape
`(n_samples, n_features)` and `kwargs` for `func`) and returns a transformed `X` of
the *same* shape. Your function `auto_filter` doesn't fit these requirements.

Additionally, anomaly/outlier detection techniques from scikit-learn cannot be
used as intermediate steps in scikit-learn pipelines since a pipeline assembles
one or more *transformers* and an optional final estimator. `IsolationForest` or,
say, [`OneClassSVM`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html) is not a transformer: it implements `fit` and `predict`.
Thus, a possible solution is to cut off possible outliers separately and build
a pipeline composing of transformers and a regressor:

```py
>>> import warnings
>>> from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
>>> warnings.filterwarnings(category=ConvergenceWarning, action='ignore')
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
>>> from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
>>> from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
>>> from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
>>> X, y = make_regression(n_samples=50, n_features=2, n_informative=2)
>>> detect = IsolationForest(contamination=0.1, behaviour='new')
>>> inliers_mask = detect.fit_predict(X) == 1
>>> pipe = Pipeline([('scale', StandardScaler()),
...                  ('estimate', MLPRegressor(max_iter=500, tol=1e-5))])
>>> param_distributions = dict(estimate__alpha=stats.uniform(0, 0.1))
>>> search = RandomizedSearchCV(pipe, param_distributions,
...                             n_iter=2, cv=3, iid=True)
>>> search = search.fit(X[inliers_mask], y[inliers_mask])
```

The problem is that you won't be able to optimize the hyperparameters of
`IsolationForest`. One way to handle it is to define hyperparameter space
for the forest, sample hyperparameters with [`ParameterSampler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterSampler.html) or 
[`ParameterGrid`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid.html), predict inliers and fit randomized search:

```py
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid
>>> forest_param_dict = dict(contamination=[0.1, 0.15, 0.2])
>>> forest_param_grid = ParameterGrid(forest_param_dict)
>>> for sample in forest_param_grid:
...     detect = detect.set_params(contamination=sample['contamination'])
...     inliers_mask = detect.fit_predict(X) == 1
...     search.fit(X[inliers_mask], y[inliers_mask])
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right, Isolation Forest is not a transformer. So no possible to include it in a pipeline. I made a calculation using your advice ans I'm trying to made my own trandformer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run step by step manually to find a problem:

```
auto_filter_transformer = FunctionTransformer(auto_filter)
X_train = auto_filter_transformer.fit_transform(X_train)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

MLPR = MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs', activation='relu', early_stopping=True, n_iter_no_change=20, validation_fraction=0.2, max_iter=10000)
MLPR.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

If each of the steps works fine, build a pipeline. Check the pipeline. If it works fine, try to use `RandomizedSearchCV`.

Comment: Good advice, by testing line by line, I have a problem with **X_train = auto_filter_transformer.fit_transform(data_num)**. Indeed, I have an **IndexError:  only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices**. I think it's due to the DataFrame used in the auto_filter function. Is-it mandatory to use Numpy Array instead of DataFrame in a FunctionTransformer ?

Comment: I test, test, test, again ... and again. No solution at all !!! It's clearly a problem of pipeline. This pipeline is not able to fit when I give a DataFrame as an imput. Any ideas ?